# E0144 значение типа "const char *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char *"

Tags: c++, классы, char, const

Изучаю язык С++ не так давно, пытаюсь повторить пример, но он упорно не хочет воспроизводится.

```
class Singer : public Worker {
protected:
    enum { other, alto, contralto, soprano, bass, baritone, tenor };
    enum { Vtypes = 7 };
private:
    static char* pv[Vtypes];
    int voice;
public:
    Singer() :Worker(), voice(other) {};
    Singer(const std::string& s, long n, int v = other)
        : Worker(s, n), voice(v) {};
    Singer(const Worker& wk, int v = other)
        : Worker(wk), voice(v) {};
    void Set();
    void Show()const;
};
```

проблема заключается в определении метода, хотя это не совсем правильно назвать.

```
char* Singer::pv[] = { "other", "alto","contralto","soprano",
                "bass","baritone","tenor" };
```

выводит что в нём ошибка.

Comment: строка `"other"` имеет тип `const char*`, а Вы пытаетесь присвоить в неконстантную строку. а так по правилам языка нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Строковые литералы нельзя изменять, по сути они `const char *`. Если бы было можно инициализировать, как вы хотите - можно было бы изменять строковые литералы, типа, `pv[0][3] = 'o';`

Исправьте на

```
static const char* pv[Vtypes];
```

Comment: Так это не я пытаюсь, так автор хочет сделать.

Comment: Значит, автор неправ. Или книжка шибко старая...

Comment: так в студии 2015 этот код работал как хотел автор. Но не стоит так делать. Но если очень-очень хочется, то можно студии разрешить так делать https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=vs-2019

Comment: А что за книжка-то?

Comment: C. Прата. Я исправил, как вы посоветовали, но всё равно не работает. 
Ошибка (активно) E0147 объявление несовместимо с "const char *Singer::pv[7]"

Comment: Вы что, только в одном месте `const` дописали?!

Comment: Нет в обоих. Теперь просто 'pv' подчёркивает. И выдаёт вышеуказанную ошибку.

Comment: https://ideone.com/9cyKYZ - смотрите сами, что у вас не так, как тут...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Автор Стивен Прата с.749]

[image: Автор Стивен Прата с.750]

Я просто повторял вслед за автором. Может это в новой редакции языка нельзя а в С++11 можно было?

Comment: так можно было только очень старых компиляторах. с++11 и даже с++03 такое не разрешали.

Comment: Просто я теперь не понимаю как мне это исправить.